# Can't connect to SQL Server - service missing

Tags: sql, sql-server

> An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server.  When connecting to SQL Server 2008, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 – Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

And the SQL Server service (`MSSQLServer`) is missing!

```
Name    State   Start Mode  Log On As   Process ID  Service Type

SQL Server Integration Services 10.0    Running Manual  NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE 7020    SSIS Server

SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER)  Running Manual  NT AUTHORITY\LOCALSERVICE   7580    Analysis Server

SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER) Running Manual  NT AUTHORITY\LOCALSERVICE   6240    ReportServer

SQL Server Browser  Running Manual  NT AUTHORITY\LOCALSERVICE   9556    SQL Browser
```

I try to run `reinstall.exe` to fix SQL Server 2008, but it shows database engine failure!

Comment: make sure that you server is started and you're using correct server name

Comment: And your question _is_ ?

Comment: If there is no `MSSQLSERVER` service running, then you don't have SQL Server installed on that machine. Connect to the machine that *has* SQL Server installed!

Comment: check your `Sql Server` services, may be these are not running. You are accessing `Sql Server` remotely..??

Comment: are you trying to connect to sql server on the same system where your sqlserver instance is installed? or you are trying to connect to remote server where your sql server is installed and your code is on different system

Comment: "I try to run reinstall.exe to fix SQL Server 2008, but it shows database engine failure" and what is this failure? post the failure message, look in windows event viewer, look in installation logs. Its curious that the other services are installed and running OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can review the **event viewer of windows** to see the problem.
You can also check the firewall is not blocking port sql server.

More details in this links

- Enable service sql server 2008 
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191454(v=sql.105).aspx
- Enable connection remote sql server 2008 
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191464.aspx